# Python regex replacement not working with group

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Trying to do the following:
string = "2"
replace to = "No 2"

using below regex in python:

```
re.sub(r'(.*)', r'No. \g<1>', '2')
```

But it returns:

```
'No. 2No. '
```

Can you please help what's going wrong?

> Note: using 3.8.5 python version

Answer (score 0):

For me it works (maybe different python versions... I'm using 3.6.11 and it seems like 3.8's [which I assume OP is using] `re` works differently):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.sub(r'(.*)', r'No. \g<1>', '2')
Out[2]: 'No. 2'
```

But, I would suggest using a better regex:

```
In [3]: re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'No. \g<1>', '2')
Out[3]: 'No. 2'
```

This is better since it only catches the digits in the string:

```
In [4]: re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'No. \g<1>', '2 3 4 5 blabla')
Out[4]: 'No. 2 No. 3 No. 4 No. 5 blabla'
```

where your regex will just take the entire string:

```
In [5]: re.sub(r'(.*)', r'No. \g<1>', '2 3 4 5 blabla')
Out[5]: 'No. 2 3 4 5 blabla'
```

Comment: When I run his regex on python 3.8.5 it gives me his results.
If I run it on 3.6.2 it gives the expected results.
Yours works the same on both.

Comment: @FrozenAra yeah, just tried it with 3.8.0

Comment: Yes, i am using 3.8.5

Comment: I recommend you to just use @ClsForCookies regex. 
I think regex behaviour changed with python 3.7

Comment: @FrozenAra Thing is the string could be anything, need to take everything.